# How to set Etsy API application permissions

Tags: etsy

I am trying to create my Etsy API app to manage my listings but I am getting a 403 error when trying to view the listing inventory page. I am not sure how to make sure my app has the `listing_r` permission. How can I check my permissions and/or set my app permissions? I verified I can authenticate through oauth and can get a bearer token and can get the listing information, but seem to be forbidden in getting the listing inventory data of my shop.

I followed Etsy's API guide on setting up the app. I am expecting to be able to view the inventory page of my listings but cannot.